# Object tracking recomendations?

Tags: python, computer-vision, tracking

I'm looking for recommendation on what exactly i should try to learn to tackle this problem:

I'm trying to analyze the physical characteristics (ie: location, velocity, and acceleration) of a ball spinning around a rim in real time. I only know Python3.7, and the spinning ball is from a video stream.

From what I've found online, OpenCV is what comes up most often, but there are lots of different types of trackers: "BOOSTING, MIL, KCF, TLD, MEDIANFLOW, GOTURN, MOSSE..etc" and i dont want to get bogged down learning the wrong thing.

What would you recommend I start with/look into? I have no experience in any computer vision programming.

Thank you